# Python: Writing efficient condition checks

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, coding-efficiency

I'm just wondering which is more efficient way of writing python between the following two approaches (also can it be improved?):

**Approach 1:**

```
for hit in hits:
    version_history = (
        get_version_history(args..)
        if request.get(SHOW_FLAG, True)
        else None
    )
    response.append(format_response(hit, version_history))
```

**Approach 2:**

```
if request.get(SHOW_FLAG, True):
    for hit in hits:
        version_history = get_version_history(args..)
        response.append(format_response(hit, version_history))
else:
    for hit in hits:
        version_history = None
        response.append(format_response(hit, version_history))
```

Comment: As this is a question that different programmers will answer differently, it is opinion-based and [is not encouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions). You could try scanning the stdlib for examples like this.

Comment: As a general rule, performing a check N times is considered N times as intensive as performing it once (favoring Approach 2).  Actual implementation performance is determined by compilers (and yes python is compiled a lot these days), affected here potential loop unrolling among other things so there may be a human benefit to Approach 1 in some cases. But if you're after syntax you might just make a function or class that encapsulates appending to all hits.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
response = [format_response(hit, get_version_history(args...) if request.get(SHOW_FLAG, True) else None) for hit in hits]
```

Although theres no discernible difference between the approaches you suggest, the former may be more maintainable.